# Manjaro only boots in GRUB “minimal bash” after deleting Deepin partition

Tags: boot, grub, manjaro

I decided to delete my Deepin partition, but when I boot, it boots a GRUB screen showing “minimal bash” like a terminal.
When I boot with “Windows boot manager”, it boots without any issue.
Also, in my Dell Bios in the boot option for Manjaro, I don’t see shimix64.efi.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to remove grub so you boot directly to windows, or are you asking how to repair your boot environment so that you can boot to the existing Manjaro installation? Is your system configured for "secured boot"?

Comment: I’m asking to repair GRUB and can use my Manjaro partition. And not, Secure Boot it’s no enabled.

Comment: Your grub must have been using Deepin's grub. You can reinstall grub for Manjaro or manually edit /EFI/grub/grub.cfg with correct UUID for Manjaro. Reinstall grub using live installer and install with ppa. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair This may also work, if you know your install's partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054032/grub-loads-instead-of-ubuntu-whenever-my-hp-streambook-reboots